# Change rectangles to circles for sankeyNetwork in networkd3

Tags: javascript, r, d3.js, htmlwidgets, networkd3

I'm having issues changing the rectangles in sankeyNetwork into circles in the networkd3 package for R. So far my onrender js code only removes the rectangles, not sure why the circles aren't being added instead.

Here's my code:

```
htmlwidgets::onRender(
  p,
  '
  function(el,x){

  //node variable
  var node=d3.select(el).select("svg").selectAll(".node");
  
  //remove node
  node.selectAll("rect")
    .remove();
    
  // add circles instead
  node
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx",sankey.nodeWidth()/2)
    .attr("cy",function(d){
    return d.dy/2;
    })
    .attr("r",function(d){
      return Math.sqrt(d.dy);})
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d.color = color_node(d); })
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return d3.rgb(d.color).darker(2); })
    .style("opacity", 0.9)
    .style("cursor", "move")
    .append("title")
    .append("foreignObject")
    .append("xhtml:body")
    .html(function(d) { return "<pre>" + d.name + "<br>" + format(d.value) + 
        " " + options.units + "</pre>"; })
    ;
    

  }
  '
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were referencing a few variables and functions that were not within scope of your function...

```r
library(jsonlite)
library(networkD3)
library(htmlwidgets)

URL <- paste0('https://cdn.rawgit.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/',
              'master/JSONdata/energy.json')
energy <- jsonlite::fromJSON(URL)

p <- sankeyNetwork(Links = energy$links, Nodes = energy$nodes, Source = 'source',
                   Target = 'target', Value = 'value', NodeID = 'name',
                   units = 'TWh', fontSize = 12, nodeWidth = 30)


htmlwidgets::onRender(
  p,
  '
  function(el,x){
  
  // map the variables you are trying to use below
  var options = x.options;
  var sankey = this.sankey;
  
  // replicate the private functions from the renderValue function that you call below
  var color = eval(options.colourScale);
  var color_node = function color_node(d){
          if (d.group){
            return color(d.group.replace(/ .*/, ""));
          } else {
            return "#cccccc";
          }
  }
  
  var formatNumber = d3.format(",.0f"),
        format = function(d) { 
            if (typeof d === "string") return d;
            return formatNumber(d); 
        }

  //node variable
  var node=d3.select(el).select("svg").selectAll(".node");
  
  //remove node
  node.selectAll("rect")
    .remove();
    
  // add circles instead
  node
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx",sankey.nodeWidth()/2)
    .attr("cy",function(d){
    return d.dy/2;
    })
    .attr("r",function(d){
      return Math.sqrt(d.dy);})
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d.color = color_node(d); })
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return d3.rgb(d.color).darker(2); })
    .style("opacity", 0.9)
    .style("cursor", "move")
    .append("title")
    .append("foreignObject")
    .append("xhtml:body")
    .html(function(d) { return "<pre>" + d.name + "<br>" + format(d.value) + 
        " " + options.units + "</pre>"; })
    ;
    

  }
  '
)
```

[image]